# Google adsense tips

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages, adsense

**HELP**

I have a personal site https://vikmaks.github.io and I was rejected by adsense and ok, I understand that. But I want to add about page, page for details of my best projects and links to them. Link are of type vikmaks.github.io/site name. Then what will adsense tell to me. It will reject me or not. You can also in answer add useful links. I want adsense not for the basic site. I create social network with adsense.
It is vikmaks.github.io/conworld

Comment: Hi Viktor, congratulations on creating your own website! I believe it has some great potential. Please don't ruin it with ads :-(

Comment: Another option is to use a different ads platform, for example [Carbon](https://www.carbonads.net/open-source)

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed possible to get adsense on your github pages websites. For more information check this link: https://flipdazed.github.io/blog/website/google-adsense-and-google-analytics. This worked for me!

Comment: Nice article about setting up Google AdSense. I was also looking for this type of thinking for my Github Pages.

Comment: Hey Hafko, what is Jekyll?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. It looks like your website is far from complete and it will not be approved by adsense. A good rule is: Make sure that your domain is at least a couple of months old. If you are applying for an adsense account from the middle East, China, India or Pakistan you may need a domain that is at least 6 months old. Apply for adsense after your website receives at least 100 unique visitors per day.